# Handling Touch Events Of A UIView That Contains A UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton

I'm not able to capture touch events from a `UIView` with a `UIButton` subview. the `UIButton` probably prevents the `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnd` events from reaching the outer view.

How can I handle those events? I tried setting `UserInteractionEnabled` to false. The touch event reached the outer view but the `UIButton` does not transition to highlighted state with this solution.

Is there a way to accomplish this without losing the natural behavior of the button?

(P.S. I do not want to use GestureRecognizers etc. because I need to get the actual timestamp of the event)

Comment: If you just wanna catch the UIView's events without GestureRecognizers, you can create a clear color UIButton , and make it's frame as the UIView's.

Comment: Screen Shot of your `UIView` that contains a `UIButton`?

Comment: why do u want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question, you can try this approach:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(yourbutton.frame, [touch locationInView:self])) { //if touch is beginning on Button

    } 
}
```